# Apache reverse proxy with subfolder

Tags: apache, proxy, debian

I've a problem that I can't solve.
I wrote my apache configuration like this:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerAdmin aa@aa.com
    ServerName xx.xx.xx.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/apache.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/localcerts/apache.key

    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off

    SSLProxyEngine on

    ProxyPass /bdn/ https://test.yy.it/
    ProxyPassReverse /bdn/ https://test.yy.it/

    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding

    Substitute "s|https://test.yy.it/|https://xx.xx.xx.com/bdn/|n"
    FilterDeclare NEWPATHS
    FilterProvider NEWPATHS SUBSTITUTE "%{Content_Type} =~ m|^text/html|"
    FilterProvider NEWPATHS SUBSTITUTE "%{Content_Type} =~ m|^text/css|"
    FilterProvider NEWPATHS SUBSTITUTE "%{Content_Type} =~ m|^text/javascript|"
    FilterProvider NEWPATHS SUBSTITUTE "%{Content_Type} =~ m|^application/javascript|"
    FilterChain NEWPATHS

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Reverse proxy works, but I loose CSS, javascript, images, ...
Why???
I've read some solution on web:

- http://makandracards.com/makandra/32973-reverse-proxying-web-applications-with-apache-2-4+
- https://serverfault.com/questions/561892/how-to-handle-relative-urls-correctly-with-a-reverse-proxy

but none of them are working.
I'm using:

- S.O. Debian 8
- Apache v. 2.4.10

Please help me!
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this tutorial:
*http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies* ??

I have used it some time ago, and everything went good!

Comment: I tried...
`ProxyRequests off
ProxyPass /app1/ https://xx.xx.com/
ProxyHTMLURLMap http://xx.xx.com /app1

<Location /app1/>
        ProxyPassReverse /
        ProxyHTMLEnable On
        ProxyHTMLURLMap  /      /app1/
        RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
</Location>`
still not working